# Unable to execute billing on Nexus 5X

Tags: android, android-billing, nexus-5

I have an app with in-app purchases. I use last billing library:

```
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:4.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing-ktx:4.0.0'
```

My problem is: every time some user on Nexus 5X device trying to make a purchase, there throwing exception:

```
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.IntentSender android.app.PendingIntent.getIntentSender()' on a null object reference

com.android.billingclient.api.ProxyBillingActivity.onCreate (ProxyBillingActivity.java:8)
android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7009)
android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7000)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1214)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2731)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2856)
android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11 (ActivityThread.java)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1589)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6494)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:438)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Exception throwing only on this device. Why it is happens? How to solve it?

Comment: Have you found the issue?

Comment: @PozzoApps No :(

Comment: We're facing a similar issue. Any luck?

Comment: @dingo I didn't solve this problem, but it's stoped to reveal for no reason long time ago. Maybe due to migration to 5+ verison of billing, maybe some other unregistered reason.